# Transform column headers to values and respective counts in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wish to transform column headers to values with their counts in Python
(counts are the value numbers under each column header per unique date and id)

**Data**

```
id  date    dd  aa
hey Q1 23   2   1
hey Q2 23   2   1
ok  Q3 23   2   1
ok  Q4 23   2   3
```

**Desired**

```
id  date    type    
hey Q1 23   dd  
hey Q1 23   dd  
hey Q1 23   aa  
hey Q2 23   dd  
hey Q2 23   dd  
hey Q2 23   aa  
ok  Q3 23   dd  
ok  Q3 23   dd  
ok  Q3 23   aa  
ok  Q4 23   dd  
ok  Q4 23   dd  
ok  Q4 23   aa  
ok  Q4 23   aa  
ok  Q4 23   aa
```

**Doing**

```
df.pivot(index="id", columns="Date", values=["dd"])
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Please clarify the question - there are no counts in your provided desired output.

Comment: my guess is that the number in `dd` and `aa` are those counts

Comment: yes @mnist this is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `set_index` + `stack` to get a Series of the repeats, then use `Series.repeat` which repeats everything in the Index (which is all the information you need after the stack). The `.drop` removes the column which indicated how many repeats were necessary.

```
s = df.set_index(['id', 'date']).rename_axis(columns='type').stack()
df1 = s.repeat(s).reset_index().drop(0, axis=1)
```

---

```
     id  date  type
0   hey  Q1 23   dd
1   hey  Q1 23   dd
2   hey  Q1 23   aa
3   hey  Q2 23   dd
4   hey  Q2 23   dd
5   hey  Q2 23   aa
6    ok  Q3 23   dd
7    ok  Q3 23   dd
8    ok  Q3 23   aa
9    ok  Q4 23   dd
10   ok  Q4 23   dd
11   ok  Q4 23   aa
12   ok  Q4 23   aa
13   ok  Q4 23   aa
```

Comment: `loc` + `lambda` if you didn't want to break the chain: `df1 = df.set_index(['id', 'date']).rename_axis(columns='type').stack().loc[lambda s: s.index.repeat(s)].reset_index().drop(columns=0)`

Answer (score 2):

Use `melt`:

```
out = df.melt(['id', 'date'], var_name='type')
out = out.reindex(out.index.repeat(out.pop('value'))).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
     id   date type
0   hey  Q1 23   dd
1   hey  Q1 23   dd
2   hey  Q2 23   dd
3   hey  Q2 23   dd
4    ok  Q3 23   dd
5    ok  Q3 23   dd
6    ok  Q4 23   dd
7    ok  Q4 23   dd
8   hey  Q1 23   aa
9   hey  Q2 23   aa
10   ok  Q3 23   aa
11   ok  Q4 23   aa
12   ok  Q4 23   aa
13   ok  Q4 23   aa
```